# angular select-ui doesn't show values with latest angular version

Tags: angularjs

I was looking at a [demo for select-ui](http://plnkr.co/edit/9DsLidTZR7RJDEq6PW0H?p=preview) in Angular, what was weird is that when i use the same code in my project, the ui-select doesn't show any values! after deep and long hours of searching I found that the demo (that is working) is using angular 1.2.18, while I am using the latest version 1.6.5.

Here is the code:

demo.js

```
var app = angular.module('demo', ['ngSanitize', 'ui.select']);
app.controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.person = {};

  $scope.people = [
    { name: 'Adam',      email: 'adam@email.com',      age: 12, country: 'United States' },
    { name: 'Amalie',    email: 'amalie@email.com',    age: 12, country: 'Argentina' },
    { name: 'Estefanía', email: 'estefania@email.com', age: 21, country: 'Argentina' },
  ];

});
```

demo.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="demo">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS ui-select</title>


  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.css">

  <script src="select.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="select.css">

  <script src="demo.js"></script>

<body ng-controller="DemoCtrl">

  <p>Selected: {{person.selectedSingleKey}}</p>
  <ui-select ng-model="person.selectedSingleKey" title="Choose a person">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select a person in the list or search his name/age...">{{$select.selected.value.name}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="person.key as (key, person) in people | filter: {'value':$select.search}">
      <div ng-bind-html="person.value.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>

</body>
</html>
```

It stops working without any errors if I switch to the latest Angular version available, can you please help telling me why?

Comment: Please, specify exactly with what AngularJS version it is failing?

Comment: I said above that i'm using angular 1.6.5, and it fails, isn't that what you asked?

Comment: Post a snippet that works with 1.2.18 so that we can see how to upgrade to 1.6.5

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: that example uses ui-select version 0.13.x as you can see from the contents of the included select.js file

```
/*!
 * ui-select
 * http://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select
 * Version: 0.13.x - 2015-09-28T02:22:34.935Z
 * License: MIT
 */
```

By looking at the [changelog](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) we can notice that support for Angularjs 1.5.x was added only in ui-select 0.14.2 - I would therefore exclude version 0.13.x supporting Angular 1.6.x.

If you do update the plunker you linked so that it uses the current version of ui-select, everything starts to work again.

Example (simplified):

http://plnkr.co/edit/6IyPS8e8mTDVLQgZYByN?p=preview

---

**NOTE**:
Since the original user that created the question later added that he already fixed the referenced library version I am adding some more insight on the problem. As per comment, the user stated:

> Thank you, but I already was having the latest select-ui on my project, the problem solved by removing the filter: {'value':$select.search} from the ui-select-choices tag!

So the problem was actually on the filter syntax. The referenced sample in the question is the third snippet in the original plunker, "**Using key for binding**".

In order to have that sample work with the latest Angularjs 1.6.x version and still support filters, I had to change the sample into:

```
<h2>Using key for binding</h2>
  <p>Selected: {{person.selectedSingleKey}}</p>
  <ui-select ng-model="person.selectedSingleKey" theme="select2" ng-disabled="disabled" style="min-width: 300px;" title="Choose a person">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select a person in the list or search his name/age...">{{$select.selected.value.name}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="person.key as (key, person) in peopleObj | filter: $select.search">
      <div ng-bind-html="person.value.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
      <small>
        email: {{person.value.email}}
        age: <span ng-bind-html="''+person.value.age | highlight: $select.search"></span>
      </small>
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
```

Notice how the filter was changed to `filter: $select.search`.
I assume than the issue is caused by a change in the implementation of the Angularjs filter. Either way, the syntax I use in the updated plunker works correctly by allowing filtering by name, age, email etc on the person object so if you need a filter, I would just use that.

Also notice that the sample seems to include a custom property filter directive "propsFilter" that apparently isn't actually used.

I have updated the linked plunker to include the specific sample from the original question.

Comment: Thank you, but I already was having the latest select-ui on my project, the problem solved by removing the `filter: {'value':$select.search}` from the `ui-select-choices` tag!